# While parsing a block mapping, did not find expected key. Failed to load github composite action.yml

Tags: runtime-error, github-actions, cicd, composite, argumentexception

Below is my caller action yml [Github Actions workflow] that gives error upon calling composite action:

```
---

name: RECYCLE_dev

  workflow_dispatch:

    inputs:

      ENVIRONMENT:
        type: choice

        options:
          - dev
          - qa
          - citest
          - cso
          - prod 

jobs:

  SEND_NOTIFICATION:

    runs-on: 'windows-latest'

    steps:

      - name: Send email notification
        uses: mybank/betech/emailnotification@mm365

        with:
          envName: "${{ inputs.ENVIRONMENT }}"
          EmailList: "knowyrtech@mybank.com"
          comments: "These comments are passed to composite actions"
```

Below is my composite actions file:

```
---

name: Send Email Notification
description: Use this composite action to send out email notifications

inputs:

  envName:

    required: true
    type: string
    default: ''

  EmailList:

    required: true
    type: string
    default: 'knowyrtech@mybank.com'

  commitPath:

    required: false
    type: string
    default: ''

  comments:

    required: true
    type: string
    default: 'default Test'
    

runs:

  using: composite

  steps:

    - name: Trigger Email Notification

      run: |
           set-location "${{ github.workspace }}\betech\scripts"
           Write-host ./ApprovalActions.ps1 -sEnv "${{inputs.envName}}" -sApprovers ${{ inputs.EmailList }} -sAccordingToEnvironment $sAccordingToEnvironment
           ./ApprovalActions.ps1 -sEnv "${{inputs.envName}}" -sApprovers ${{ inputs.EmailList }} -sAccordingToEnvironment '"Recycle completed for "${{inputs.envName}}" environment"'
```

I get the below error when running the composite action:

```
Error: mmctech\betech\mm365\emailnotification\action.yml:
Error: mmctech\betech\mm365\emailnotification\action.yml: (Line: 40, Col: 12, Idx: 992) - (Line: 41, Col: 190, Idx: 1327): While parsing a block mapping, did not find expected key.
Error: System.ArgumentException: Unexpected type '' encountered while reading 'action manifest root'. The type 'MappingToken' was expected.
   at GitHub.DistributedTask.ObjectTemplating.Tokens.TemplateTokenExtensions.AssertMapping(TemplateToken value, String objectDescription)
   at GitHub.Runner.Worker.ActionManifestManager.Load(IExecutionContext executionContext, String manifestFile)
Error: Fail to load mmctech\betech\mm365\emailnotification\action.yml
```

Can you please suggest what could be the issue with the yml file?

On side note would like to know if it is possible to call composite action in a file which is not named `action.yml`.

Comment: Did this occur when an `ENVIRONMENT` was selected? `envName` is required but its default value is an empty string. Have you verified this?

Comment: @Azeem The composite workflow underlines syntax with red and states `Missing required root key on` I did set the default for `envName`

Comment: Red line on which line exactly?

Comment: I kept the error on Public repo here: https://github.com/knowyrtech/callingcompo/actions/runs/5089857231/jobs/9147974889 and workfile file here: https://github.com/knowyrtech/callingcompo/actions/runs/5089857231/workflow

Comment: defining a `shell`? is that specific to `composite` actions ? becoz i never had to state the shell in normal and `reusable` actions ... I'm expecting it will use default `pwsh` shell

Comment: That error is self-descriptive and it's about your action. You missed `shell` property in your action. See [`runs.steps[*].shell`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runsstepsshell) which is required for a composite action.

Comment: Are you using VSCode to write your workflows and/or actions? If yes, you may use its GitHub Actions extension to quickly debug such issues as they're automatically highlighted in the editor.

Comment: i m using github action UI to write. Not using VSCode or any editors

Comment: I believe that also highlights such issues. Anyways, is it fixed with `shell: powershell` or `shell: pwsh` as you're using a Windows self-hosted runner, IIRC?

Comment: yes `shell: powershell` fixed the issue. But i wanted to see if it is documented that for composite `shell:` has to be explicitly specified and not defaults like for other actions.

Comment: It's right there in the link I share above i.e. with `run` it's required to specify `shell` too. And, that's under **composite** action.